# codeigniter routing error

Tags: php, codeigniter

http://mysite/products/create

```
Not Found

The requested URL /products/create was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at site5.example.com Port 80
```

routes.php =>

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'products';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

model =>

```
<?php
class Products_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();

    }

    function get_products($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('products');
            return $query->result_array();

        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('products', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    function set_products()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'text' => $this->input->post('text')
        );

        return $this->db->insert('products', $data);

    }

}
```

controller =>

```
<?php
class Products extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('products_model');

    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['products'] = $this->products_model->get_products();
        $data['title'] = 'Products archive';
        $this->load->view('products/index', $data);
    }

    function view($slug)
    {
        $data['products'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
    }

    function create()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $data['title'] = 'Create a products item';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            //$this->load->view('templates/header', $data); 
            $this->load->view('products/create');
            //$this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }
        else
        {
            $this->news_model->set_news();
            $this->load->view('products/success');
        }   
    }

}
?>
```

view =>

```
<h2>Create a news item</h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('products/create') ?>

    <label for="title">Title</label> 
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" /> 

</form>
```

Why did i get this error ? Where is the error ?

Comment: If you can reach that function by `http://mysite/index.php/products/create`, seems you should configure your htaccess at the first place. Because that typical mvc url, `http://domain/controller/function` doesnt need a route rule to works.

Comment: But for http://mysite/products/create  i got error, Not Found

The requested URL /products/create was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at site5.example.com Port 80

Comment: did you have .htaccess set up? I believe you are try to remove index.php from your uri, and for that, you will need to set up a htaccess rewite rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'products/index';
$route['products/create'] = 'products/create';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Do it like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'products';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Do not specify method, because than CI will look for "index" controller in application/products folder which does not exists. If you specify path in route than it looks for a path.

Comment: I changed the routes.php ,but for http://mysite/products/create  i got error, Not Found

The requested URL /products/create was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at site5.example.com Port 80

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder (esp to myself).

If you create something like this

```
$route['products-view'] = 'products'; //refer to products.php
$route['products-create'] = 'products/detail/create'; //refer to products/detail.php
```

you will face a routing error when trying to open `products-create` because you have a file name `products.php`, it will think there is a method named `detail` in the file. CI will open to `products` and there is no such method name `detail` and will throw error.